# is there a way to trigger a gif animation when the container is in the scroll view

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have couple of gif animation through out a basic HTML CSS website and i was wondering if there is a way to trigger the gif when its in the scroll view and play it once . I am doing other animations using scrollMagic but i cant seem to get control of the gif animation that well. Im not that familiar with the properties that i need to listen or keep track with event listener to play or bind control of the gif when scrolling. if there is any examples that explains similar case using gifs with the combination of screen view or scrolling please do let me know thank you!

Comment: You could add an initial image with the same ratio and change the image source to the gif one whenever it was scrolled into viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put an IntersectionObserver on each such gif and when it is visible in the viewport give it the correct src and when it goes out of the viewport remove the src. This will ensure it plays again when it comes back into view.

```js
 function callback(entries) {
   for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++ ) {
    entries[i].target.src = (entries[i].isIntersecting) ? entries[i].target.getAttribute('data-src') : "";
   }
}
const gifs = document.querySelectorAll('.gif');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
for (let i = 0; i < gifs.length; i++) {
  observer.observe(gifs[i]);
}
```

```css
.gif {
  position: relative;
  top: 150vh;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 20vh;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="" class="gif" data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBSrY.gif" />
```